# Inifinite chain of magnetic dipoles

Tags: magnetic-fields

I would like to calculate the magnetic field generated for a chain made of magnetic dipoles (all equivalent) separated $2a$ not aligned with the chain. It must be something similar to this reference:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8vCR.png) Halsey, T. C., & Toor, W. (1990). Structure of electrorheological fluids. Physical review letters, 65(22), 2820

But in my case it would be for a infinite chain of **magnetic** dipoles separeted 2*a (center to center distance between the particles of the chain) instead electric dipoles and the dipoles are **not aligned with the chain**. Something like this figure:

[image]

I have tried to solve this problem, but in reference [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8vCR.png) there is not a useful explanation of  how to obtain the solution of the magnetic field...

I have tried to use cylindrical coordinates and decompose all the vectors calculating the total field at the point due to all the particles using the superposition principle, but I have not reached a satisfactory result, there must be an easier way...

Could someone guide me or give me some hints to solve the problem?

Note: I know that if dipoles are not aligned with the chain that configuration is not a equilibrium configuration, but at the end I want to do this to know the field generated close to the chain, because these magnetic particles with dipoles are going to be frozen, but the dipole direction can change its direction.

Comment: I’m not sure that there is a closed form. The easiest way of getting a formula is by Fourier series along $z$. Periodizing about $z$ amounts to sampling the Fourier transform. The magnetic field is now an infinite sum.

Comment: @lpz thank you for the suggestion. I will try to simplify the problem to 2D, focus only on coodinates in X=0, Y>0 plane and 2D dipole too (0,my, mz), maybe that way I can find something